# Redirect sub domain with source port to destination port

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, srv-record

I want redirect subdomain:port to subdomain:destination_port . It possible ? i see use SRV Record but can't use subdomain:port.

Example:

> sub.domain.com:1234 to sub.domain.com:2345

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible via dns. The only (reasonable) ways to accomplish this would be to either redirect the client to the new url (eg, http 302) if the protocol supports it, or to either proxy the connection from the old port to the new, or to redirect it through for example, iptables nat/mangle rules.